# Sequence of execution of "always" and "generate" blocks

Tags: verilog, hdl

[image]

I'm fairly new to Verilog. I have been writing some code by myself and need some help. The following is the code for a serial to parallel interface.

```
enter `define MEM_SIZE 10

module Tx_Serialctrl_10reg(RESETB, CLK, CSB, SDATAIN,  SDATAOUT, MEM_DATA_OUT);
/* I/O Declarations */
input RESETB;    // Active low synch. reset
input CLK;       // Clock
input CSB;       // Active low chip select
input SDATAIN;   // Serial data input
// Parallel input data

output SDATAOUT;              // Serial data output
output[`MEM_SIZE*8-1:0] MEM_DATA_OUT;  // 19 x 8-bit unpacked memory output
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

/* I/O Reg-Wire Declarations */
wire RESETB;    // Active low synch. reset
wire CLK;       // Clock
wire CSB;       // Active low chip select
wire SDATAIN;   // Serial data input

wire SDATAOUT;              // Serial data output
wire[`MEM_SIZE*8-1:0] MEM_DATA_OUT;  // 10 x 8-bit unpacked memory output
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/* Internal Signals */
reg[15:0] shift_reg;  // Keeps the data during I/O operation
reg rd_wrb;           // Indicates read or write operation
reg[3:0] dcounter;    // Counter for received bits
reg[7:0] mem_data[`MEM_SIZE-1:0];  // A 10 x 8-bit memory
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/* The main state machine */
//integer icnt;  // For the 'for' loops

always @(negedge RESETB or posedge CLK)
begin
    if(~RESETB)
    begin
        dcounter <= 4'h0;
        shift_reg <= 16'h0000;
        rd_wrb <= 1'b0;
        /* Initialize memory : here it is initialized to all zeros */
//        for(icnt=0; icnt<`MEM_SIZE; icnt=icnt+1)
//            mem_data[icnt] <= 8'h00;
        mem_data[0] <= 8'b0000_0110;  //0x06
        mem_data[1] <= 8'b0001_1111;  //0x1F
        mem_data[2] <= 8'b1111_0011;  //0xF7
        mem_data[3] <= 8'b1111_1111;  //0xFF
        mem_data[4] <= 8'b0110_1111;  //0x6F
        mem_data[5] <= 8'b0110_1111;  //0x6F
        mem_data[6] <= 8'b0110_1111;  //0x6F
        mem_data[7] <= 8'b0000_0110;  //0x06
        mem_data[8] <= 8'b0001_1111;  //0x1F
        mem_data[9] <= 8'b1111_0011;  //0xF7

    end
    else
    begin
        if(~CSB)  // Do any operation only when CSB = 0
        begin
            dcounter <= dcounter + 1'b1;
            if(dcounter == 4'h0)  // First bit to be received
            begin
                rd_wrb <= SDATAIN;  // Decide read or write
                shift_reg <= {shift_reg[14:0], SDATAIN};  // Shift the data in
            end
            if(dcounter == 4'h8) // Load shift reg if it is a read operation
            begin
                if(rd_wrb)  // Read operation
                begin
                    shift_reg[15:8] <= mem_data[shift_reg[5:0]];
                end
                else
                    shift_reg <= {shift_reg[14:0], SDATAIN}; // Shift the register
            end
            else if(dcounter == 4'hF)  // 16th edge received
            begin
                if(~rd_wrb)  // Write operation
                begin
                  
 mem_data[shift_reg[12:7]] <= {shift_reg[6:0], SDATAIN};
         

      end
                shift_reg <= {shift_reg[14:0], SDATAIN}; // Shift the register
            end
            else
            begin
                shift_reg <= {shift_reg[14:0], SDATAIN}; // Shift the register
            end
        end
        else  // CSB is high : do nothing reset everything in I/O path
        begin
            dcounter <= 4'h0;
            rd_wrb <= 1'b0;
        end

    end

end

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/* Other assignments */
assign SDATAOUT = shift_reg[15];

genvar pk_idx;
generate for (pk_idx=0; pk_idx<`MEM_SIZE; pk_idx=pk_idx+1)
begin
    assign MEM_DATA_OUT[((8*pk_idx)+7):(8*pk_idx)] = mem_data[pk_idx][7:0];

end

endgenerate
endmodule
```

I have a lingering doubt even after seeing some testbench simulations.

1. List item`  begin
   dcounter <= dcounter + 1'b1;
   if(dcounter == 4'h0)  // First bit to be received

At the first clk posedge, what is the value of the counter? In case it is updated to 1'b`1 instantly, then how does the "if(dcounter == 4'b0)" ever get executed?

2. Another serious doubt is about the execution of generate block with respect to always block.
3. `mem_data[shift_reg[12:7]] <= {shift_reg[6:0], SDATAIN}`

Is this shift operation correct?

After every SerialInput bit and counter update, does execution come out of always block and then execute the generate block fully i.e. assign all 80 bits?
If the entire generate runs at every clk posedge, is it the right way to write my serial bits into the MEM_DATA_OUT[ : ]?

For more info, these are 8 data bits in each of 10 registers, which are sent further ahead as control bits to various analog blocks.

Comment: And if you _do_ make a specific and simple example, and it _doesn't_ do what you expect, then you can swap out the example you have now for the simplified one, say what it does, what you expect, and ask why they're different.

Comment: You're thinking of HDL as if it were software.  It's not.  There is no "order of execution" between blocks in the design.... both blocks are mapped to hardware, and wired together.

Comment: @BenVoigt So does the generate block execute fully at each clock posedge?

Comment: I am adding the testbench simulations. If possible kindly answer my doubts.

Comment: With regards to question 1, does [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/378614/verilog-comparison-after-non-blocking-assignment/378619#378619) help?